# Add leading Zeros to a number that will be printed in a string along with text

Tags: swift

I'm trying to build an app for fun in order to make a bunch of calculations for me. I need some help adding leading zeros to the number when I combine it with text in a string.
By the way, I've only been coding for a full 4 hours total in my life so I'm not well versed.

```
print(String(format: "%03d", magwind))
```

This works as a test when I'm only trying to show the number alone and no assign it to a label on my UI

```
magneticwindLabel.text = String("Magnetic Wind: \(magwind) @ \(truewindvelocityInt!) Kts ")
```

When I use this it will only print out the single int from my earlier equations

```
magneticwindLabel.text = String(format: "%03d", "Magnetic Wind: \(magwind) @ \(truewindvelocityInt!) Kts ")
```

This is what I have right now and it changes my label to some random numbers that don't reflect my equations above

Example:

> magwind = 10 or 5 or 120
>   truewindvelocityInt = 25

What I would like is for the label on my UI to be changed to

> "Magnetic Wind: 010 @ 25"
>   "Magnetic Wind: 005 @ 25"
>   "Magnetic Wind: 120 @ 25"

Comment: magneticwindLabel.text = NSString(format: "%03d", "Magnetic Wind: \(magwind) @ \(truewindvelocityInt!) Kts ") as String

Comment: @ElTomato No need for `NSString`. And your suggestion is wrong even for `NSString`.

Comment: Late edit, I also would prefer that the wind velocity doesnt have the same leading zeros if possible

Comment: Did my answer solve your question or do you still have a question?

Answer (score 2):

Your attempt is in the right direction but not quite there.

Change:

```
magneticwindLabel.text = String(format: "%03d", "Magnetic Wind: \(magwind) @ \(truewindvelocityInt!) Kts ")
```

to:

```
magneticwindLabel.text = String(format: "Magnetic Wind: %03d @ %@ Kts", magwind, truewindvelocityInt!)
```

Don't try to use string interpolation (the stuff in `\( )`) with string formats. If you are going to use string format then you must use only string formats in that line.

Just for completeness, there is another way to combine both approaches.

```
magneticwindLabel.text = "Magnetic Wind: \(String(format: "%03d", magwind)) @ \(truewindvelocityInt!) Kts"
```

But that's more clumsy. I don't recommend that but I'm showing it so you can how this stuff can be fit together.

Note that when using regular string interpolation, you don't need the `String( )` part around the whole thing.

That last example can be split into two steps which has a few advantages:

```
let magWindStr = String(format: "%03d", magwind)
magneticwindLabel.text = "Magnetic Wind: \(magWindStr) @ \(truewindvelocityInt!) Kts"
```